# How to subscribe Web API on Azure Messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I have 2 Web APIs developed on ASP.NET Core. The idea is: the WebAPI_1 sends a message to the Azure Service Bus and then WebAPI_2 has to catch this moment and read it shortly after the message is sent. I understand how to catch this moment is I have a console app instead of WebAPI_2, but I am not sure how to subscribe WebAPI_2 on such the event happening in Azure Service Bus.
Below is the code where I have WebAPI_1 and the Console App.

WebAPI_1 (Sender):

```
public class QueueService : IQueueService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public QueueService(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public async Task SendMessageAsync<T>(T serviceBusMessage, string queueName)
    {
        var queueClient = new QueueClient(_config.GetConnectionString("AzureServiceBus"), queueName);
        string messageBody = JsonSerializer.Serialize(serviceBusMessage);
        var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));

        await queueClient.SendAsync(message);
    }
}
```

And this is how I send it:

```
 await queue.SendMessageAsync(obj, "myqueue");
```

And this is the Console App (Receiver):

```
Main(){
        queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, queueName);

        var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
        {
            MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
            AutoComplete = false
        };

        queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
}

private static async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
{
    var jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
    Model obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Model>(jsonString);
    Console.WriteLine($"Person Received: { obj.Field1} { obj.Field2}");

    await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
}
```

But I want WebAPI_2 to be able to receive the messages instead of the Console App.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Receiving messages requires a continuous job. ASP.NET Core Controller, as you've probably found out, is not the right place as it's not running continuously and is intended to respond to the request. For a continuous execution, a background service, or task, is the right option. ASP.NET Core has an option to run a [`BackgroundService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services) that could be used for exactly what you need.

There are multiple blog posts with the details in case you want to get some inspiration:

- [Getting Started With Azure Service Bus Queues And ASP.NET Core Background Services](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-azure-service-bus-queues-asp-net-core-background-services/)
- [Using An ASP.NET Core IHostedService To Run Azure Service Bus Subscriptions and Consumers](https://damienbod.com/2021/07/20/using-an-asp-net-core-ihostedservice-to-run-azure-service-bus-subscriptions-and-consumers/)